# long running process id based on grep condition and send mail

Tags: unix, grep, ps

```
ps -eaf | LaunchKTRProcess | grep -v grep
```

- this command will give me , full details of process, and i have to manually check his Running time and kill the process.

Comment: ,but i want some command which search process based on my grep condition, and running more than 10 min, so it ll provide me all list of process id, so i can use that process_id for sending alert mails.

Comment: Edit your question with the whole phrasing. People do not expect to have a question split in pieces, some in the question and some in comments.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
ps -e | sed 1d | egrep -v '^ *[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +([^ ]|00:0.):'
```

gives the ps of all processes which run for more than ten minutes (I use `sed 1d` to remove the `ps` header line because not every `ps` has an option to suppress it); you can filter the output based on further conditions. Then

```
| awk '{print $1}'
```

extracts the PIDs (1st column).